# mod_rewrite error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite in my new website.

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rwr=$1
```

**index.php file**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['rwr'])) {
    if (substr($_REQUEST['rwr'], -1) == "/") {
        $modrewrite = substr($_REQUEST['rwr'], 0, -1);
    } else {
        $modrewrite = $_REQUEST['rwr'];
    }
    $modrewrite = explode("/", $modrewrite);
}
if (isset($modrewrite) && $modrewrite[0] != "") {
    $category = $modrewrite[0];
} else {
    $category = null;
}

if (isset($modrewrite[1])) {
    $service = $modrewrite[1];
} else {
    $service = null;
}

if (isset($modrewrite[2])) {
    $identification = $modrewrite[2];
} else {
    $identification = null;
}
```

With this the link `www.domain.com/service/webdesign/works` go to -

```
$category = "service";
$service = "webdesign";
$identification = "works";
```

**This works but I want to optimize it:**

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?category=$1&service=$2&identification=$3
```

**index.php file**

```
$category = $_GET['category'];
$service = $_GET['service'];
$identification = $_GET['identification'];
```

But it doesn't work. Why? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your rule should work fine for URL in question. It could be your Apache configuration and/or similarly named files that causing it. Lets take your example URL `/service/webdesign/works`. It is possible that you have file named `service.php` then Apache may ignore that rewrite rule for some reason.

You can use this approach:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# the rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]*)(/([a-z0-9\-_]+))?(/([a-z0-9\-_]+))?$ index.php?category=$1&service=$3&identification=$5 [NC,QSA,L]
```

This is a tested and working solution.

Comment: hello men something is dont work with the code you give me when i go to / or /service just redirect to http://localhost/xampp/splash.php why?

Comment: I don't know why it does not work for you. It worked fine on my PC -- I would not post it untested. Please check your Apache error log. If nothing -- please enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) in your httpd.conf and check rewrite log for details.